# VLC package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: vlc, dependencies

When I try to install VLC media player this pops up:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.3ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-randr0 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

Can someone please tell me what this means?

How can I get around it? (if possible)

P.S. I am also receiving similar pop ups when trying to install most programs.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you happen to use a PPA for VLC at all? This lead to a problem for me.

Comment: How did you install it ? eg terminal, software center or with a .deb

Comment: Please post your sources.list.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install unmet dependencies.

You need to install:

libavcodec53 libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat53 to install this
libavcodec53, libgsm1 libschroedinger-1.0-0, libavcodec53, libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat53, gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg, gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad, ffmpeg

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsm1 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libavcodec53 \
    libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat53 gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg \
    gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad ffmpeg
```

If it says to install any unmet dependencies then install them first after finishing installing all those dependencies then you should be able to install vlc.

I hope it will help you

Comment: Dependencies are automatically resolved using `apt-get` or `aptitude`...