# Cannot install VLC due to unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, vlc

I am using a 32-bit version of Ubuntu, and I am trying to install VLC. But every time I do it, it shows unmet dependencies.

I know this issue was addressed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180635/vlc-package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved) but the problem is not solved in that thread.

I have run the solution referred to in that thread and this is the output:

```
gaidin@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libgsm1 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libavcodec53 \libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat53 gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg \gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad ffmpeg

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
Package gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad' has no installation candidate
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain @Braiam but how exactly do I do that? I tried but it is showing all those links and stuff and in the end, I cannot save the edited version.

Comment: You only need to use nautilus (for example) and navigate to that path `/etc/apt`. Then open the file named `sources.list` copy the contents and paste it here. Or, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) then type `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, then press enter it will print the contents, you copy and paste like usual.

Answer (score 1):

VLC doesn't use gstreamer, it uses its own system. Go to software & updates and make sure universe/multi is selected, then chose vlc in Software Centre. One of your servers might be down, so you might need to update or change tbe "download from:" field to something else like Main Server.

Also, what is the result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`